Error on a WHILE loop? PL/pgSQL_postgresv10
I have a problem with a PL/pgSQL script (postgres v10).
The goal is simple: list the schemas of a database, the tables for each schema with their number of records + a hash for each table.
The problem I have is for large tables where I am 'out of memory'. After some research, I code to do it in batches. However, when testing the code, it tells me the error
ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
WHILE offset < row_count LOOP

I have looked before/after the loop, nothing to report. And if I comment out the entire loop, the code works, a sign that the loop is the problem.
Can you help me? Thank you (you will find the code below).
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify_migration()
RETURNS TABLE (schema_name TEXT, table_name TEXT, row_count BIGINT, table_md5 TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
    schema_rec RECORD;
    table_rec RECORD;
    row_count BIGINT;
    batch_size INTEGER := 10000;
    offset INTEGER := 0;
    table_md5 TEXT;
    batch_md5 TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR schema_rec IN
        SELECT s.schema_name
        FROM information_schema.schemata s
        WHERE s.schema_name NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    LOOP
        FOR table_rec IN
            SELECT t.table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables t
            WHERE t.table_schema = schema_rec.schema_name
              AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        LOOP
            table_md5 := '';
            offset := 0;
            EXECUTE format('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.%I', schema_rec.schema_name, table_rec.table_name)
            INTO row_count;

            WHILE offset < row_count LOOP
                EXECUTE format('
                    SELECT md5(string_agg(t::text, ''''))
                    FROM (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM %I.%I
                        ORDER BY 1
                        LIMIT %L OFFSET %L
                    ) t', schema_rec.schema_name, table_rec.table_name, batch_size, offset)
                INTO batch_md5;
                
                IF batch_md5 IS NOT NULL THEN
                    table_md5 := md5(COALESCE(table_md5, '') || batch_md5);
                END IF;
                
               offset := offset + batch_size;
            END LOOP;
            
            RETURN QUERY
            SELECT
                schema_rec.schema_name::TEXT,       -- Cast explicite en TEXT
                table_rec.table_name::TEXT,         -- Cast explicite en TEXT
                row_count,                          -- deja un BIGINT
                table_md5;                          -- déjà en type TEXT
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


offset is a reserved SQL keyword. Use a different name.

Why not using the information that is available in pg_stat_user_tables?

Thank you very much for your solution. It works perfectly (I even made it evolve already)
It's true that I didn't think to check the reserved words. I feel so stupid (and he could have told me too ^_^)

OFFSET is a reserved word in SQL:

Table C.1. SQL Key Words



Key Word
PostgreSQL
SQL:2023
SQL:2016
SQL-92




OFFSET
reserved, requires AS
reserved
reserved





You can replace it with a name that isn't a reserved word, such as curr_offset, and you should be OK:
curr_offset := 0;
EXECUTE format('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.%I', schema_rec.schema_name, table_rec.table_name)
INTO row_count;

WHILE curr_offset < row_count LOOP
    -- etc...


using double quotes should to work too "offset", but surely, better not to use it

Thank you very much for your solution. It works perfectly (I even made it evolve already)
It's true that I didn't think to check the reserved words. I feel so stupid (and he could have told me too ^_^)
